# insert current date_time in table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This query works ok:

```
INSERT
INTO I#journal
  (
    Type_,
    Mndnr,
    Obj,
    Status,
    Reason,
    Date_
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'CHECK_TRX',
    '1047',
    '123123123',
    'NEW',
    '',
    To_Date('10-04-2013 14:35:07', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  );
```

But I want to insert current date automatically instead of `To_Date('10-04-2013 14:35:07', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

So I tried `Now()`

```
INSERT
INTO I#journal
  (
    Type_,
    Mndnr,
    Obj,
    Status,
    Reason,
    Date_
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'CHECK_TRX',
    '1047',
    'werwerwer',
    'NEW',
    '',
    Now()
  );
```

but I got an error:

```
Error at Command Line:18 Column:5
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "NOW": недопустимый идентификатор
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: use `SYSDATE` to get current system date..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation lists the [functions available in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions.htm); those from other databases might not work, particularly non-standard (ANSI) ones.

Read up on [`SYSDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions191.htm#sthref1621) and [CURRENT_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions044.htm); and if greater precision is required, [SYSTIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions192.htm) and [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions045.htm).

The difference between the `SYS` and `CURRENT_` versions is whether you're using the server time or the session (client) time, which may or may not be a significant distinction for you.

Answer (score 1):

try current_date or current_timestamp instead